# calling javascript function from html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is the problem.. 
i have a javascript file which is named *javascript.js* like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 function init()
  { 

    //code goes here

  }
  }
```

now the index.html file has a command button  which should call the init() function.

```
   <html>
   <head><script src=javascript.js ....></script>
   <body><button type="button" onclick="init()">Call Init!</button></body>
   </html>
```

But it doesn't call it. Nothing happens as expected. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: This is clearly not the code, and it has several syntax errors. No way someone can help you unless you show the real code or at least are paying attention to details when explaining it.

Comment: @6502 Ease off. Sure, the poster made some syntax errors, but gave more than enough to answer their question. I don't know about you but I don't copy and paste 100+ lines when I ask a question and think I would be annoyed if someone else did.

Comment: @dgeare Thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: @dgeare: Sorry if this for some reason sounds harsh, but this question is quite low quality. The title itself is already bad (more or less like "preincrement doesn't work in C++")... bad syntax in the javascript part, bad tagging (now fixed, but javascript is one thing, jquery is another), bad html (where is `</head>?`, what is `....`?), no homework (any error messages in the javascript console?). Actually after seeing so much sloppiness I didn't even pay attention to the content. I bet the same happened to many other viewers.

Comment: @6502 Thanks for all the advice! Will try to follow it in the future

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should define your function outside `$(document).ready()` scope.

Comment: While they SHOULD do this will it keep the function call from functioning? EDIT: Is the answer related to scope? (since a function in javascript is just an object?)

Comment: Isn't there any way i can access it when its INSIDE $(document).ready() scope??

Comment: @PasanWijesinghe while I'm not 100% on the if possible.  Why would you want to?  A function won't be called simply by defining it so there is NOTHING to be gained by doing this...

Comment: @Jared This is a javascript snake game. The problem I had is: All the functions are setup inside the $(document).ready() scope. The init() is called to restart the game. I need to call it from index.html. I temporarily solved the problem by RELOADing the page whenever i need to restart the game manually

Comment: @PasanWijesinghe Do you have access to the js source?  If so move the methods OUTSIDE of the `$(document).ready()` You won't lose any functionality and will gain yourself the ability to use the method like you are eluding to in your question.  The exception to this is if you have multiple `objects` that need to have the same method names in which case you would want the methods inside of the object for scope reasons.

Comment: @PasanWijesinghe See this (http://jsfiddle.net/8zcVg/) jsFiddle of this in action...

Comment: @Jared: It is definitely not a good idea to move just everything in the global scope. Ever heard of namespace pollution?

Comment: Absolutely, in their situation where they are wrapping in a DOM ready event this is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 3):

The `onclick` attribute will be executed in a global context. Your `init` function is scoped to the anonymous function which you pass to jQuery. Three solutions:

- Move the `init` function outside of the ready function, into the global scope
- export the `init` function by making it a property of the global object: `window.init = function() {…};`
- as you use jQuery, you should not need to define any handlers in attributes. Instead use (inside the ready function): `$("button").click(function init() {…});` Even better use an `id` to reference the button.

Answer (score 2):

Try viewing the page in chrome. Hit F12 to view the console. You'll be able to quickly debug the issue. At first glance, however, I do see that your $(document).ready function is not closed properly. Add ');' at the end of the code you included. Also, add quotes around javascript.js in your script tag. See if that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the syntax errors. But they were not the problem. I just typed the 'format' of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

```
function init()
{ 
   $(document).ready(function() {
       //code goes here
   });
}
```

You can use flag too in order to keep track if the "//code goes here" proceeded or not. So in case of document not ready yet, you can use while loop with setTimeOut function for some pause interval "In order to not hang the client browser".